# How to check if a country belongs to Europe

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, list, countries

I'd like to check if the country name provided belongs to Europe.
Does anyone know of a list of european countries that can be used in a Ruby project?

I'd like to do something like this:

`spain = Country.named('Spain')`

`spain.parent # => 'Europe'`

`japan = Country.named('Japan')`

`japan.parent # => 'Asia'`

https://github.com/jim/carmen/ lets me list subregions of a country, but not a country's parent.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try [that gem](https://github.com/hexorx/countries) if you really need whole gem for this. You should be able to do:

```
Country.find_all_countries_by_region('Europe')
```

to get countries in Europe.

Comment: Mr Manners reminds the Gentle Poster to remember to mark this as the correct answer, _after_ you install and audition that library...

Answer (score 1):

Check out the Wikipedia article for a complete list. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_European_countries